# Install MSI on remote computer using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am trying to write a Powershell script which will deploy software on a collection of WS2016 servers. I am a local administrator on all these servers. Here's what I have so far:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Computer = 'myserver.contoso.com'
$SplunkMSI = '\\mylocalbox\C$\Splunk.msi'
$InstallDir = 'C:\Apps\Splunk\'

$sb = {
    param($installer, $dir)
    Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\windows\system32\msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList "$installer INSTALLDIR=$dir AGREETOLICENSE=Yes /qn /norestart /L*v C:\temp\splunkInstall.log" -Wait -NoNewWindow
}
Write-Host "Deploying Splunk to host $Computer"
Invoke-Command -Computer $Computer -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $SplunkMSI, $InstallDir -ErrorAction Stop
```

When I run this script, I get prompted for credentials, and then I see the output of the Write-Host, but then... nothing. I have to manually terminate the script.

I logged onto the remote host, but see no evidence that the MSI was executed or failed to execute.

Anyone see a smoking gun?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and copy the MSI file to the remote servers and run it *locally*  ;-)

Comment: `/i` is missing, the command is `msiexec /i msipackage.msi`

Answer (score 0):

ya, it looks like it's looking for $installer and $dir in the script block but they're not specified